# how to lookup image from different excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating an excel workbook file with one of the column containing a title of an image that is in another excel workbook file, that excel file contained huge database of images how to lookup images form that excel workbook file with their individual title

Note: these are two different Excel workbooks. And the condition is we can't merge file because imageDatabase file is so heavy up to 25MB for that reason excel is get not responding or force close.

file for example: 
https://drive.google.com/a/flygoldfinch.com/file/d/0B9VV_J4sKTatdDBEZ01GNHg3Y0k/view?usp=docslist_api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any reference to a cell in Excel can be performed on any other sheet, be it in the same file, or an outside file.

A reference to another sheet within the file looks like this:

```
='sheetname'!M20
```

The same thing works if that sheet is in a different file

```
='[file.xlsx]sheetname'!$H$726
```

Knowing that the reference will work that way, you can write any formula with it.  This includes VLOOKUPs, or anything else you need to do.

A good shortcut to make this easier is to have both files open, click the cell you want to make the reference in, type =, then switch to the other file, click the cell you want, and hit return.  Your reference is made.